# How to get count of rows from SP & generic repository in asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, t-sql, asp.net-mvc-4

I have following stored procedure:

```
CREATE  PROCEDURE [dbo].[SPname]
AS
SELECT Count(*) FROM [dbo].[Table]
GO
```

How I call this in the code:

```
Convert.ToInt32(_genericRepo.Context.Database.SqlQuery<Table>("EXEC SPname").FirstOrDefault())
```

And what error I have:

```
The data reader is incompatible with the specified 'Table'. A member of the type, 'Id', does not have a corresponding column in the data reader with the same name.
```

Does anybody help me? I'm using asp.net mvc4 with generic repository.

Comment: Try giving some name to the Count(*) like `SELECT Count(*) CountOFTable FROM [dbo].[Table]`

Comment: In the stored proc. You are returning a count with no column name. that might be the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
int countoftable = _genericRepo.Context.Database.SqlQuery<Int32>("EXEC SPname").FirstOrDefault();
```